# How to configure to run typescript output in browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, tsc

I have a TypeScript project with a few real TypeScript classes, not just functions. I have 1 file per class. There are classes that depend on other classes. I can compile these whole TypeScript to JavaScript with `tsc`. I can also run locally the JavaScript output with Node. It runs fine. Actually I run a small test class. I don't use any third party library.

I want that a browser can run the generated JavaScript. So I tried to include the whole JavaScript output in my HTML website.
But the JavaScript does not run in a browser. I just tried to create an instance from one of the generated JavaScript class. I also copied the needed require.js file to my HTML project.

My question is: How can I configure `tsc` and `requirejs` that a browser can run my generated JavaScript?

My `tsc` generated require calls with relative paths. It is not a mystery that this does not work in a browser, but I don't know which variant would work. I am a bit upset, because I read so many tutorials and tried so many combinations and I am still not wiser. Many tutorials mention `webpack`, `gulp`, `baseUrl` and such things without showing an example that would run in a browser.

My `tsc` config is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions":
  {
    "module": "none",
    "target": "ES2018",
    "removeComments": true,
    "rootDir": "Source",
    "outDir": "Build"
  },

  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: check this https://westerndevs.com/TypeScript-with-AMD-and-Gulp/ and change target in tsconfig to es5. whitch is supported by all browsers

Comment: I am thankful for this answer. This is the kind of explanation I am looking for. I could run my typescript output in a browser.